# Make the times from a log file relative to the starttime

Tags: bash, logging

I have a logfile with this format:

```
10:33:56 some event occurs 
10:33:57 another event occurs
10:33:59 another one occurs
```

I want to make the times relative to the start time:

```
00:00:00 some event occurs 
00:00:01 another event occurs
00:00:03 another one occurs
```

using a bash script. That would allow me to compare better different execution delays.

Comment: Are these in 24 hour format ? What happens if the time goes onto the next day ?

Comment: That would be another question. The problem is stated for this kind of log files. E.g.: Jenkins shows the log on this format. But you can post your own solution or tell how to fix this case.

Comment: I'm asking about these logs, you've only shown 3 different times in the same minute, and never mentioned anywhere what type of log it is...

Answer (score -2):

One can make this script `rebase_time.sh`:

```
adddate() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        log_file_hours=`echo $line | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ [/:]+"}; {print  $1}'`
        log_file_minutes=`echo $line | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ [/:]+"}; {print  $2}'`
        log_file_seconds=`echo $line | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ [/:]+"}; {print  $3}'`
        log_date="$log_file_hours:$log_file_minutes:$log_file_seconds"
        if [[ -z "$first_date" ]]; then
            first_date=$log_date
        fi
        StartDate=$(date -u -d "$first_date" +"%s")
        FinalDate=$(date -u -d "$log_date" +"%s")
        diff=$(date -u -d "0 $FinalDate sec - $StartDate sec" +"%H:%M:%S")
        echo $diff ${line#$log_date}
    done
}
cat "$1" | adddate
```

and call it this way:

```
./rebase_time events.log
```